# React Native set default iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, react-native-ios

I want to set a default simulator for my react native project so if I run the script
`yarn ios` or `npx react-native run-ios` it always start the "iPhone 12 Pro Max".

- using the `--simulator` flag once does not change the default simulator, and the next time I run `yarn ios` or `react-native run-ios` it starts on different simulator
- When I run `yarn ios` the app starts with `iPhone 10` and when I run `npx react-native run-ios` the app starts with `iPhone 8`. If I remove either of these simulators via xCode, the project does not start with mentioned scripts and throws an error that iPhone 10 or iPhone 8 was not found.

So my question is where in the project the value of these simulators are saved, and how to change it. Is it set somewhere in `.xcworkspace` or `.xcodeproj`? If someone clones this project and runs the app might start on different devices on their machine.

***Note: I am not searching for answers including setting `--simulator` flag***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently no official way besides `--simulator` to set device for `run-ios` as [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-simulator-ios#specifying-a-device)

You can try to edit in ./node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js the default in end of file:

```
var _default = {
...
options: [{
    ...
    default: 'iPhone 8'
  },
...
}
```

"react-native": "0.63.4"

Comment: This is what I was searching for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json file

**Change this:**

```
"scripts": {
     ...
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
     ...
  },
```

**To this:**

```
"scripts": {
     ...
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 12 Pro Max'",
     ...
  },
```

I hope this help you out.!

Comment: I have mentioned in the question `I am not searching for answers including setting --simulator flag`

Comment: It works for me, thanks. A little correction, the right line should be this: `"run-ios": "react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 12 Pro Max'",`
Look the simple quotes for simulator value.